# Alt key codes. I can't do 2 digit codes

Tags: keyboard, alt-code

Whenever I want to make alt symbols that require 2 numbers, I only make what the last number represents. For example, I wanted to make the ♪ symbol using alt+13 but it makes the ♥ symbol which is alt+3. If I wanted to make the ♫ symbol using alt+14, it makes the ♦ symbol which is alt+4.

How do I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this happen with `[Alt] + 64` too? Because this sounds like your `1` key is broken.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to use the numbers from the number pad on your keyboard. Make sure to switch the **Num Lock** on.

Comment: If it were off, they wouldn’t be getting anything (well, they *would*, but it would be equivalent to pressing `Alt+Navigation-Keys`, not what they are getting).